# PL SQL Cursor For Loop: add up values in same variable and output the summed total

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to calculate the GPA within a function that accepts a studentID as an input. My issue is that the variable `lv_gpa_calc` isn't adding to itself when the loop works through the cursor set. I added the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to make sure that it's working through the cursor set correctly and that prints to the screen the correct individual row values of what `lv_gpa_calc` should be, but when it gets returned in the function in a SQL block, it isn't adding all of those values together. Can you not set a variable to itself within a CURSOR FOR LOOP?

Update: initializing the `lv_gpa_calc` fixed the problem where the variable value wasn't adding to itself.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION CALCULATE_GPA 
(p_studentID IN number)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  CURSOR cur_gpa IS
      SELECT grade, grade_value, credit_hours
      FROM grade
      JOIN enrollment USING (Grade)
      JOIN section USING (term_code, subject_code, course_number, section)
      JOIN course USING (subject_code, course_number)
      WHERE student_ID = p_studentID;

  lv_gpa_calc NUMBER(4,2):=0;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_gpa IN cur_gpa LOOP
  lv_gpa_calc:= lv_gpa_calc + ((rec_gpa.grade_value * rec_gpa.credit_hours)/rec_gpa.credit_hours);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_gpa_calc);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN lv_gpa_calc;

END CALCULATE_GPA;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that variable `lv_gpa_calc` is not initialized. Adding whatever to `NULL` will result as `NULL`.

Simplified working test case:

```
--DROP TABLE my_numbers;

CREATE TABLE my_numbers (
  id NUMBER
);
/

BEGIN
  FOR l_i IN 1..10 LOOP
    INSERT INTO my_numbers VALUES (DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM);
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
/

SELECT * FROM my_numbers;
/

DECLARE
  CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT id
      FROM my_numbers;

  l_sum NUMBER(10) := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN cur LOOP    
    l_sum := l_sum + rec.id;    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_sum = ' || l_sum);
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sum = ' || l_sum);
END;
/
```

Important line is:

```
l_sum NUMBER(10) := 0;
```

Without initialization `:=0` it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the input! appreciate it. Do you know why you have to initialize a variable before the BEGIN section to 0 or some value in order for it to work?

Comment: Because if it is not initialized the value is NULL. Then most binary operations (with two operands, like sum) will give the NULL value.